# Rest of StackView doesn't shift after resizing subview

Tags: ios, uistackview

An ImageView is at the top of my UIStackView.
Every time that I programmatically change the height of the ImageView, the rest of the stack view doesn't shift up or down. It stays in the same place.

To change the height of the imageview, I'm using

```
imageView.frame.size.height = 100
```

How can I cause the rest of the stackview to 'refresh'?

Comment: How did you configure subviews of the stack view?

Comment: I constrained their Top to 0

Comment: If you used auto layout, setting frame will not work at all. Also I don't think you can change struct's property directly.

Comment: Do you know how I could do it?

Comment: Change the constraint.constant.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Could you please explain further?

Comment: If your imageView has edges constraint to its superview which is the `StackView` and the size of imageView is decided by auto layout, changing `frame` will not work.

If you want to update StackView's frame by its subview(imageView), you need to update imageView's constraint so it will update superview's size.